# How to reference MSA in work order?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

How do companies reference a Master Services Agreement in work orders or statement of work? What language is normally used to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical provision would say on the face of the work order or statement of work, often at the top or bottom on the front side of the front page, sometimes in a text box, something like:

> This work order incorporates by reference all provisions of the Master
>   Services Agreement of June 14, 2014 ("MSA"), that are not expressly
>   contradicted by the language of this work order. **The MSA contains a
>   binding arbitration clause and a waiver of certain lien rights.** A copy
>   of the MSA is available for inspection at all times in the general
>   contractor's office or on the general contractor's website.